# С# WPF Combobox Вывод на экран свойства включаемого объекта

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть такой класс

```
public class GeodezeBindedCordinateModel
    {
        public AdvancedCordinateModel SK42Cordinate { get; set; }
        public CordinateModel PZ90Cordinate { get; set; }
    }
```

У класса `SK42Cordinate` есть свойство Name, его нужно вывести в combobox на экран.
Вот `xaml` который я пытался использовать для решения, не помогло

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding itemsCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="SK42Cordinate.Name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение как всегда, проще, чем можно было подумать.

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SK42PointsPointsForDirectAngle}"   SelectedItem="{Binding SK42SelectedPoint1}">
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SK42Cordinate.Name}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ComboBox>
```